# Adding a upvote/score to an existing tasks controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm very new to Rails and I'm attempting to build a Todo app with the ability to upvote Todos. Currently my Todo model is as follows;

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house

  default_scope { order("score, created_at DESC") }
end
```

My Todos controller is as follows;

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :assign_house_from_invite!
  before_filter :ensure_house!

  def index
    @todo = Todo.new user: current_user
    @todos = current_user.house.todos
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params.merge(user: current_user, house: current_user.house))
    @todo.save
  end

  protected

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:task, :vote)
  end

  def assign_house_from_invite!

  end

  def ensure_house!
    redirect_to new_house_path if current_user.house.nil?
  end

end
```

and my Todos erb partial is;

```
<div class="row input-append">
  <%= form_for(@todo, remote: true, id: "new_todo_form") do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_field :task, :placeholder => "Add new task", :class => "span2", :id => "appendedInputButton", :type => "text" %>
    <%= t.submit '+', :id =>'plus', :class => 'btn', :type => 'button' %>

  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="todos" class="row">
  <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <%= render partial: 'todo', locals: {todo: todo} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm wondering what do I have to add to each of these to enable each task to have an initial score assigned of 0 and then for it to be able to be incremented when it is upvoted? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know something about javascript and ajax? Instead of submit, you add a button which triggers an ajax post to a controller action that will increase the score and return data (like json for instance) to map the new status, without reloading the full index

Comment: I don't know much javascript/ajax but at least this points me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Add to your controller an "upvote" def. Then add it to your routes file. Then add a button / link to your view that has an AJAX call to that new 'upvote method'. As far as the model itself, add a 'score' value to the Todo model object. Initially this will be null - you can do one of three things - 1) add an 'after_initialize' method to the model that sets it to zero initially, 2) :default => 0 on the field definition (this will be set on save), or 3) you can check for a null value in your upvote method and set it to the correct value before incrementing